# SQL Query for reading & operator within the quotes.!

Tags: oracle

I want to search 'R&D' in my database using SQL query but it is not doing so correctly.It is not reading & as it is but initiating the & operator function instead even though it is under quotes.
How can I do so.?

Comment: Where are you running your query? If it's in Toad (or other GUI, such as SQL Developer) there's an option to turn off substitution variable prompting. Or, if you add `set define off` before your query and then run both as a script, that would work too (especially in SQL*Plus).

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
'R' || chr(38) || 'D'
```

38 is the code of the `&` character in Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
where t.Column = 'R&' || 'D'
```

`&` is considered a variable only when it's followed by another character.

Comment: Great..!! Both method worked..Thank-you so much..!! :)